# Date comparision not working in my application

Tags: java, android, date

> the if statement in the function getCallDetailsAgil() is not working. the statement is in the switch case where it is checking if the call type is MISSED
>   Can anyone please help me out? startdate and enddate are publiic date objects. i am just trying to ocunt all missed calls between thos two dates.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_incoming);
        Intent i = getIntent();

        //

    }

    private int getCallDetailsAgil() {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);

        int count=0;
        while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
            String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
            Date dc = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
            String dir = null;
            int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);

            switch (dircode) {

                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:

                    System.out.println("---------" + startdate.toString());
                    System.out.println(dc.toString());
                    System.out.println("---------" + enddate.toString());
                    System.out.println(dc.before(startdate)+" "+dc.before(enddate));

                    if (dc.before(startdate) && dc.before(enddate))
                        count++;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return count;

    }
```

Comment: Can you share what is the error message or the output that you are getting? Help us understand your problem.

Comment: There isn't one. The code runs smooth. Its just that the if statement , where I'm checking that the call date is between the given date, is not getting executed. and Hence returning 0 as count.

Comment: Rather than `Date`, which is old and poorly designed you may consider `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). However if you insist on `Date`, I believe you are requiring `dc` to be *before* start date *and after* end date, which isn’t possible (assuming start date is before end date). Why not just `startdate.before(dc) && dc.before(enddate)`? The corresponding method for `Instant` is `isBefore`. java.time is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I just posted the edited code in proper format. After looking closely i have found that on the terminal i get this output :                                                     
              ---------Wed Sep 04 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 3918
              Mon Sep 24 14:58:26 GMT+05:30 2018
              ---------Sat Sep 21 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 3918
              true true                        the output shows year value = 3918 for stat and end date. even though i a m selecting 2018 as on the date picker dialog

Comment: your output says `true true` - so `count` must be increased. If you receive zero then bug is somewhere else (i.e. startdate / enddate are swapped at some point etc)

Comment: Also, if you want to count events between start and end then condition must be `dc.after(startdate) && dc.before(enddate)`

Comment: Thanks for formatting the code. Could you also post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead?

Comment: Can you put count++ out of the if statement? Just for discard that it is a variable scope problem?

Comment: It’s not a scope problem, @BrankVictoria. `count` is declared above the `while` loop.

Comment: @OleV.V. I have seen it, but what if he has another count declared outside of that function?

Comment: Thanks everyone. i have found my mistake. It was just due to the fact that the date picker was returning date in Gregorian format.